# why callback is a number not function in React Scheduler?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I suspect the Fiber has a bug

I use some Hooks in React-Native of 0.59. My react version is 16.8.3.

```
  flushedNode.next = flushedNode.previous = null;
  // Now it's safe to call the callback.
  var callback = flushedNode.callback;
  var expirationTime = flushedNode.expirationTime;
  var priorityLevel = flushedNode.priorityLevel;
  var previousPriorityLevel = currentPriorityLevel;
  var previousExpirationTime = currentExpirationTime;
  currentPriorityLevel = priorityLevel;
  currentExpirationTime = expirationTime;
  var continuationCallback;
  try {
    [ this is the mistake ]  continuationCallback = callback();
  } finally {
    currentPriorityLevel = previousPriorityLevel;
    currentExpirationTime = previousExpirationTime;
  }
```

Now, let me show the bug.

```
flushedNode is {
    callback: 3,
    expirationTime: 220678.60500000097,
    next: null,
    previous: null,
    priorityLevel: 3,
    __proto__: Object
}
```

Callback should be a function but it is a number showed `3`,so the app is crashed, why?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest unstable version, https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/scheduler/src/Scheduler.js#L320

```
function unstable_scheduleCallback(priorityLevel, callback, options) {
   var newTask = {
    id: taskIdCounter++,
    callback,
    ...
   }
   return newTask
}
```

so yes, it should be the callback you used to schedule. And this callback is later used to execute the work in `workLoop`, https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/scheduler/src/Scheduler.js#L185